# Group Theory- S3 table

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

$\begin{matrix}
 &  e&  a&  b&  c&  d&f \\ 
 e&  e& a &  b&  c&  d&f \\ 
 a&  a&  b&  e&  d&  f&c \\ 
 b&  b&  e&  a&  f&  c&d \\ 
 c&  c&  f&  d&  e&  b&a \\ 
 d&  d&  c&  f&  a&  e&b \\ 
 f&  f&  d&  c&  b&  a&e 
\end{matrix}$

This is the group table I have created for $S_3$ group. Now, I want to find out the regular representation for the group element $c$ or what is $D_{ij}$.I also have to write every steps in detail.

Comment: Okay, so what have you done?

Comment: I am actually not been able to understand the question first of all, so haven't started even a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by $D_{ij}$?

Comment: I don't think that the table is correct, Is it ? I think there should be AA=E

Comment: @user44400: $D_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th matrix entry of the matrix $D$.

Comment: No, $aa \neq e$ because $a$ is a cycle of length 3 (think of the cycle $(3 1 2)$). There are 3 such cycles and 3 transpositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on, this is really not difficult. The left regular representation of $c$ is the matrix of the left translation by $c$ in the algebra $\mathbb{Z}S_3$. Thus, according to your table:

$ca=f$, $cb=d$, $cc=e$, $cd=b$, $ce=c$, $cf=a$.

In other words,

$ca=0a + 0b + 0c + 0d + 0e + 1f$,
$cb=0a + 0b + 0c + 1d + 0e + 0e$,
$cc=0a + 0b + 0c + 0d + 1e + 0f$,
$cd=0a + 1b + 0c + 0d + 0e + 0f$,
$ce=0a + 0b + 1c + 0d + 0e + 0f$,
$cf=1a + 0b + 0c + 0d + 0e + 0f$,

so the matrix is

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, I should seriously check my notes. Can you also help me to figure out the normal sub-group and the factor group for S3

Comment: For every $n$, there is a privileged normal subgroup inside $S_n$, usually denoted $A_n$ - the alternating group. This is the subgroup consisting of all *even* permutations and has $\frac{n!}{2}$ elements. In your case, it is exactly $\{(1 2 3), (3 1 2), (2 3 1)\}$. By Lagrange's theorem, the factor group should have cardinal $\frac{|S_3|}{|A_3|}$, that is 2. Thus the factor group is the abstract group with 2 elements, call it $\{1, x\}$ with $x^2=1$. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, what is the normal sub-group and factor group from the above table.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha: notice in the table that $c^2=d^2=f^2=e$, so these are elements of order 2. But only transpositions are of order 2, and they are always odd; since we are looking for even permutations, this means that we want the remaining ones: $A_3=\{e,a,b\}$. The factor group is, in general, *not* a subgroup of a given group, therefore you won't find it in the table. In this very special case, since it is isomorphic to the abstract group of order 2, you may take it to be any of $\{e,c\}$, $\{e,d\}$ or $\{e,f\}$.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha: You should _really_ check your notes.

Comment: Thanks.......Group theory is a new course at our uni and I must tell you that i am really struggling with it. Any books that you would like to recommend.....